# Looking for a Paper: RBS Guide to Inflation-Linked Products

Tags: swaps, inflation

I wonder if any of you have an access to "The Royal Bank of Scotland (2003) Guide to Inflation-Linked Products. Risk." paper. It was in the bibliography of Mercurio's "Pricing Inflation Indexed Derivatives" paper which is hosted on http://www.fabiomercurio.it/Inflation.pdf

I've checked online, library, etc. but couldn't find it so far.

Thanks,

Comment: https://www.worldcat.org/title/royal-bank-of-scotland-guide-to-inflation-linked-products/oclc/53815522&referer=brief_results  I'd try making an interlibrary loan request.

Comment: I have it... although I'm not sure I can post it online due to copyright

Comment: It's too bad there is no DM here :) Is it okay if I share an e-mail adress over here ?